# Flutter Push notification from a ASP.net rest API

Tags: asp.net, push-notification, flutter

I use ASP .NET RestAPI as my Flutter App's backend and want to send notification to my app when some event occurs. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: FCM is the best way for both platform!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Flutter has first party plugin [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging) for that.

It's easy to integrate Firebase SDK to your flutter application.

Once setup the Firebase SDK to your flutter application you can use [FCM rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to send push notification to your application.

Remember to prepare a backend API to save your clients (devices) FCM token, because you need a device token to send a push notification to a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

You can send FCM notification using your server or from client side from flutter app. Use the Rest API for the FCM and send the notification easily.

Checkout this post: https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-fcm-rest-api-7719925f2e3e

Post API URL:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Request Body:

```
{
"to": "<FCM Token>",
"priority": "high",
"notification": {
    "title": "Hyree FCM testing",
    "body": "Testing the fcm notification for different fcm token",
    "sound": "default"
}
```

}